# ConTeXt: Margin notes ragged right in both margins

Tags: horizontal-alignment, context, marginnote, sidenotes

I'm struggling with margin notes in ConTeXt. Here I have a MWE of what I could achieve, with the invaluable help of many people in StackExchange. Now, I want all margin notes (those in left as in right margin) ragged right. I've tried to find a way in ConTeXt Reference Manual, 2013 version but in 4.7 it says: "Text in the margin. FIXME. The syntax of the margin commands has changed in mark IV". Nonetheless, I've tried to get the right ragged text I want with this, buy I couldn't do that. Next, I looked in the web but I found nothing clear to me. Could someone obtain ragged right text in both margins over the MWE? Thanks!

```
\mainlanguage[es]
\language[es]
\usecolors[xwi]
\definecolor[marca][h=e80000]

\newdimen\Margin
\Margin=3.5cm
\newdimen\MarginRaise
\MarginRaise=56ex

\setuppagenumbering
[alternative=doublesided, location=]

\setuplayout[backspace=20mm,width=120mm,height=middle,footer=\bodyfontsize, header=3\bodyfontsize,headerdistance=\bodyfontsize,bottom=3\bodyfontsize,location={middle},margin=\Margin,rightmargin=4.5cm,marking=on]

\setupinterlinespace[small]

\setupmargindata[location=both, align=left,stack=yes, stack=continue, style=\tfx\setupinterlinespace] 

\newcounter\MyMarginalNote
\def\mnote{\dosingleempty\domnote}

\def\domnote[#1]#2%
 {\doglobal\increment\MyMarginalNote
 \high{{\tfxx\color[marca]{\MyMarginalNote}}}%
  \inouter
   {{\tfx\color[marca]{\MyMarginalNote:}}
    \doifsomething{#1}
     {\expanded{\textreference[#1]{\MyMarginalNote}}}\tfx\it {#2}}}

 \starttext
 \input ward\mnote{\input {knuth}}
  \input bryson
  \input dawkins
  \input douglas
  \input reich\mnote{\input{zapf}}
  \input reich
  \input zapf

  \stoptext
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two types of margin mechanisms in MkIV: `margindata` and `marginframed`. In `margindata` the margin text is simply set in a `\vbox`; in `marginframed` the margin text is set in `\framed` (technically, a lower level command than framed, but it helps to think of it as a framed). For most cases, `margindata` is sufficient; `marginframed` is useful when you want to use some of the framed parameters (`offset`, `frame`, etc.) to change the visual appearance.

The following macros are defined as `margindata`:

- `\inleftmargin`, `\inrightmargin`, `inoutermargin`, `\ininnermargin`
- `\inleftedge`, `\inrightedge`, `\inoutedge`, `\ininneredge`
- `\atleftmargin`, `\atrightmargin`.

The following are defined as `marginframed`:

- `\inleft`, `\inright`, `\inouter`, `\ininner`, `\inmargin`, `\inother`.

Now, where things get a little confusing is that for marginframed some of the parameters are set using `\setupmargin` while some are set using `\setupmarginframed`. `align` is one of the parameters that is set using `\setupmarginframed`. (It is possible that the `align` for `\setupmarginframed` gets inherited from `\setupmargindata`; I consider the current behavior a misconfiguration).

So, in your example, you should either

1. Use `\inoutermargin` (the `margindata` variant) instead of `\inouter`
2. Use `\setupmarginframed[inouter][align=flushleft]`.

I show the complete example with the second alternative below. I also cleaned up some of the other code (using `measures` and ConTeXt counters; the advantage of ConTeXt counters is that you have easily change the conversion if you wish)

```
\mainlanguage[es]

\definecolor[marca][h=e80000]

\definemeasure[Margin][3.5cm]

\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided, location=]

\setuplayout
  [
    backspace=20mm,
            width=120mm,
           height=middle,
           footer=\bodyfontsize,
           header=3\bodyfontsize,
   headerdistance=\bodyfontsize,
           bottom=3\bodyfontsize,
         location={middle},
           margin=\measure{Margin},
      rightmargin=4.5cm,
          marking=on,
  ]

\setupinterlinespace[small]

\setupmargindata[stack=continue, style=\tfx\setupinterlinespace] 
\setupmarginframed[inouter] [align=flushleft]

\definecounter[MyMarginNote][numberconversion=numbers]

\def\mnote{\dosingleempty\domnote}

\def\domnote[#1]#2%
    {\incrementcounter[MyMarginNote]%
     \high{{\tfxx\color[marca]{\convertedcounter[MyMarginNote]}}}%
  \inouter
     {{\tfx\color[marca]{\convertedcounter[MyMarginNote]:}}%
      \doifsomething{#1}
       {\expanded{\textreference[#1]{\convertedcounter[MyMarginNote]}}}\space
       \tfx\it {#2}}}

\starttext
\input ward\mnote{\input {knuth}}
\input bryson
\input dawkins
\input douglas
\input reich\mnote{\input{zapf}}
\input reich
\input zapf
\stoptext
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much! Did you learn that studying the code (or producing it, you have such expertise in ConTeXt that i think it's possible you are developing the system) or in some documentation?

Comment: @Miguel: I had never used margin notes in the past and read the source to understand what was happening. I am not one of the developers of ConTeXt; just a user.

Comment: Wow! I'd like to be able of do that! But it's impossible with my knowledge and skills. Thank you very much for your time and work!